# Android SlidingPaneLayout Fade

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, slidingpanelayout

I am trying a prototype app with SlidingPaneLayout. My SlidingPaneLayout is gray and body view is pure white.
but when i slide in, the small visible area of body page goes slightly dark or overlaying with dark screening. all i want is pure original white color of that body view.

I tried couple of Methods to switch off these but seems impossible. such as

```
SlidingPaneLayout sp = (SlidingPaneLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainSlider);
sp.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```

or following property in XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainSlider"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="none" <!-- try one -->
    android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"  <!-- try two -->
    android:fadingEdge="none"  <!-- try three -->
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

[image]

[image]

Any one of you, have you ever done this successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the fade color to transparent:

```
SlidingPaneLayout sp = (SlidingPaneLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainSlider);
sp.setSliderFadeColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Comment: Wow, it really works. @ianhanniballake. it is possible to do the same in xml view it self?

Comment: Looking at the [SlidingPaneLayout's LayoutParams source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.java#1391), there is a `dimWhenOffset` value which would function similarly, but it is not exposed in XML via a custom attribute so you cannot set it in XML. Calling the method in `onCreate()` will ensure that it always appears undimmed though.

Comment: That's okay. Thanks anyway